# convert certain special characters to ascii in php

Tags: ascii, converters

I need a php script that convert certain special characters to ascii code( , . / - and all the letter with accent)

eg.

```
original:
Dingo a accidentellement fait tomber la pièce porte-bonheur de Mickey tout au fond du lac. Le Professeur Von Drake va utiliser son camping-car et le transformer en sous-marin pour explorer les eaux profondes.

result:
Dingo a accidentellement fait tomber la pi&#232;ce porte&#45;bonheur de Mickey tout au fond du lac&#46; Le Professeur Von Drake va utiliser son camping&#45;car et le transformer en sous&#45;marin pour explorer les eaux profondes&#46;
```

I've tried htmlspecialchars() doesn't seems work out it only convert the characters which are special significance in HTML

Comment: not sure if this helps http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation of [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) you will see:

> If you require all input substrings that have associated named entities to be translated, **use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) instead**.

Comment: htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES); it converts some of it but the it doesn't really convert the "dash, comma, slash and all the other punctuations"

Comment: Why are you trying to do that exactly? There might be a better solution if you explain. I have the feeling that we're dealing with the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) ;)

Comment: I was given one sample xml files to convert it into whole bunch of different formats and one of them converts all the punctuations and stuff into ascii codes I am not sure how to do.

Comment: Here's an idea: first you use `htmlentities()` as expected. Then, you use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) to map the chars that `htmlentities()` did not replace to the ones you want. [This table](http://www.ascii-code.com/) should be useful.